# Is there a better / correct term for the de facto usage of ‘ironic’?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, irony

The word ‘ironic’ is known to be quite frequently misused, to the point that some dictionaries have actually started accepting the de facto usage as another definition, usually calling it *situational irony*.

Is there a better, more appropriate term for this construct?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid use any of the various of the word "irony" in the new term?

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/irony

Comment: @NateMPLS: Ahh, I never dreamed as a kid that I would grow up and one day utter the words "I like the oatmeal" — but I do.

Comment: @NateMPLS, well there goes the rest of my night… `:-|`

Comment: @Syntech: Hahaha! Somebody referenced the Oatmeal here a couple days ago.  I squandered a perfectly wonderful night that I will never get back!  :-P

Comment: possible duplicate of [What word means what many people think 'ironic' means?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6618/what-word-means-what-many-people-think-ironic-means)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem resistant to the idea that *situational irony* itself *is* the most appropriate term for the concept. In fact, it has been [recognized as a form of irony since the eighteenth century](http://books.google.com/books?id=5_FaXOuJyGsC&printsec=frontcover&hl=en&ei=vXXUTajWEIvGsAOL0JmSCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=book-thumbnail&resnum=1&ved=0CEwQ6wEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22situational%20irony%22&f=false), and the term "situational irony" has been around for decades ([here are two citations from 1960](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22situational+irony%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&safe=off&sa=X&ei=LHbUTZegJoimsQPcm6ywCQ&ved=0CB0QpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1960%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1960&tbm=bks)). There's nothing improper about it at all.

Comment: So then people who nag that the use of the term “ironic” is incorrect in that context are just being pedantic?

Comment: @Synetech: yes; and not just pedantic, but incorrect in their pedantry.

Comment: So they’re dilettantes as well?

Okay then; thanks.

Comment: Ironic, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The things that are incorrectly ascribed to irony fall into a few categories. Some are coincidence:

> Ironically, I ended up in the same
>   store as my mother.

Sometimes it's just bad luck:

> I hate cats and ironically, my new
>   girlfriend has seven.

And a more extreme example is just tragedy:

> I was always afraid of getting cancer,
>   then ironically I had a stroke.